# How to make the 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar' style's Action Bar's app icon and title separate？

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I often use 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'(extends ActionBarActivity) style to make Action Bar.
Now I use the 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'(extends Activity) style.
I found the Action Bar's app icon and title are different between two styles.
I wan to separate the app icon and title in 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar' style.

Comment: You can use just one of them, and then make the desired property inherit from the other style.

Comment: @ m iav But now I need use 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar' .